# wwdc 2013 sample code

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask this, but I was trying to find the WWDC 2013 sample code.  I came across this: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/WWDC-Downloader

I haven't done that much from the command line or anything with curl, ruby, etc.  I did install RVM from some online tutorial.  My apple Id has spaces in it.  I try to run the scrip like this

```
wwdcdownloader 'my id'
```

I get an error with this message:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/wwdcdownloader-20.13.5/lib/wwdcdownloader.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in login': undefined method `theAccountName=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Am I doing this right? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello I written a free Cocoa application to do this task.

You can download all WWDC2013 sample code both IOS and OS X. All downloaded samples are automatically placed on Downloads folders.

[image]

[Application download](http://www.disco.germinara.it/FGSAMPLECODEDOWNLOADER.app.zip)

Comment: Fantastic.  Grazie.  One though though.  It appears that the last few (7) samples from Graphics Animation on to the end do not get downloaded (Mac free sample code). About 5 of the iOS items at the end of the list don't get downloaded either, from iPhoneCoreDataRecipies on to the end.  Also, it appears that free and prerelease download the same data (on iOS).  Any updates to fix this so we can get the missing files would be great.  Thanks again.

Comment: I know this is free, but it's also a security problem. It saves people's Apple ID and password in clear text in its preferences file. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: I just build the 2.0 version for WWDC 2014 sample code. That have this improvements: password saved in keychain access, if file exist in download directory it is not downloaded again (you must delete manually the file to start download it again), some interface change including new log info about documents that application can't download automatically. This is the link http://www.germinara.it/corsoprogrammazione/FGSampleCodeDownloader_2_0.app.zip

Comment: @FrancescoGerminara Can you please share the link from where you are downloading sample codes?

Comment: Also it seems its downloading all free sample codes too along with WWDC sample codes

Answer (score 4):

You can download all sample code for WWDC 2013 from the following URL.

http://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Then search for "wwdc" or look under "WWDC 2013 Sample Code" node.